# have_posts() do not return private posts in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

In my theme, in the category.php page, its codes are:

```
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php
              echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'"><h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3></a>';      
        ?>
     ?>
```

If the posts in the category is published, then they will show in the category page. However, if I set them to private, then they will not show.

How to let private posts to show as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Published` and `private` are two separate settings, one refers to the status, the other one to the visibility. A post can be `published` and set to `private` at the same time. If that is the case, it will be in `have_posts()` for logged in Administrators and Editors who own the post (and have the title prefix "Private: "). Drafts will never show.

`post status` = `published` | `draft`

`post visibility` = `public` | `private` | `password protected`

If you want to override that default behavior, you have to use your own WPQuery or change the main query with something like:

```
function my_private_posts_in_categories($query) {
    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category()) {
        $query->set('post_status', ['private', 'publish']);
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 15);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_private_posts_in_categories');
```

Comment: My contents in the private posts are used to provide content to the category page. So I want to be able to use the contents in the private posts and show in the category page that is visible to public.

Comment: @alancc Added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Can I set so that only for a specific category('news'), the private and publish posts will show? For all other categories, only the publish posts will show, as normal.

Comment: Sure: `WP_Query::is_category()` accepts one argument, which can be `id`, `name` or `slug`. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_category/ for details.